# Create a Custom Excel Function that returns Mysql Data

Tags: mysql, excel, function, vba

i want to create a custom excel function which takes the cell value as a parameter to query the mysql database

```
Function excelmysql2()

    Dim odjDB As ADODB.Connection
     Dim sqlstr As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim oRS, nRec, oFld
    Dim Row


     '----------------------------------------------------------------------

    Set odjDB = New ADODB.Connection

    Sheets("Sheet1").Select

    odjDB.Open "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};" & _
    "SERVER=192.168.0.64;" & _
    "DATABASE=mifos;" & _
    "Port=3307;" & _
    "USER=root;" & _
    "PASSWORD=admin;"




    Set oRS = odjDB.Execute("SELECT account.customer_id FROM mifos.account WHERE (mifos.account.account_id= '" & Range("A3").Value & "')")

    nRec = 0
    Row = 3

    Do While Not oRS.EOF
        For Each oFld In oRS.Fields

            Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Row, 3).Value = oRS("customer_id")


            Row = Row + 1
            On Error Resume Next
            oRS.MoveNext

        Next
    Loop

    oRS.Close
    odjDB.Close

End Function
```

as you noticed in have the cell number set in the function
because i couldn't find a way to have it dynamic.
i want to be able to use the function like any excel function where i can pass the value of a cell and get the queried value from mysql

what should i put instead of the Range("A3") to be able to use this function in excel by passing cell values?
(EX: =excelmysql2(A1)...)

thanks

Comment: change `Function excelmysql2()` to `Function excelmysql2(myAccntId as String)` and then change `Range("A3").Value` to `myAccntId`

Comment: oh sorry @simoco I have just noticed your comment. if you add an answer I can delete mine no problem.

Comment: @mehow, there's no problem:) You've covered it in more details and also I like this part `Sheet1.Range("C3").CopyFromRecordset oRs`, +1 from me)

Comment: @simoco had to revise the answer actually. forgot you can't populate more than 1 cell using a worksheet fn ;)

Comment: @mehow, yeah, absolutelly, concentrated on function parameter and missed that UDF is going to edit cells content.

Answer (score 0):

the below eg. relates to your question

Use it and just change the parameters....

It illustrates a query that returns a (closing rate `"MEND"`) FX rate based in the month and year from a Table called rates in the database called finance

> ```
> SELECT rates.MEND 
>    FROM rates 
> WHERE rates.Cur =  'USD' 
>  AND  rates.Month = JAN 
>  AND  rates.Year = 2015
> returns 14.35
> ```
>
> Table : rates
>
> Cur | Month| Year | MEND
>
> ZAR | JAN  | 2015 | 1.453
>
> USD | JAN  | 2015 | **14.35**

```
Function MySQL_Month_endRate(Curr As String, Monn As Integer, yearr As Integer) As String
'##################
'##  Connection  ##
'##################

Dim conn As Variant
Dim rs As Variant
Dim cs As String
Dim query As String


Dim Table_Name As String
Table_Name = "rates"

Dim Database_Name As String
Database_Name = "finance"


Set conn = CreateObject("adodb.connection")
Set rs = CreateObject("adodb.recordset")


     cs = "DRIVER={MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver};"
cs = cs & "DATABASE=" & Database_Name & ";"
cs = cs & "SERVER=127.0.0.1"

conn.Open cs, "root", "root" 'UserName and Password else WindowsNT Autentication






'####################
'##      QUERY     ##
'####################

query = "SELECT rates.MEND FROM rates WHERE rates.Cur =  '" & Curr & "' AND  rates.Month = " & Monn & " AND  rates.Year = " & yearr

'Curr As String, Monn As Integer, yearr As

Debug.Print query
rs.Open query, conn


'####################
'##   RECORD SET   ##
'####################




     Do Until rs.EOF


'       row = row + 1
'       Cells(row, 5).Value = rs.Fields("Serial key").Value
      Debug.Print rs.Fields("MEND").Value


      MySQL_Month_endRate = rs.Fields("MEND").Value

       rs.MoveNext
     Loop


'#####################
'##      Return     ##
'#####################










Set rs = Nothing
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing


'myRibbon.Invalidate
'End
errline:
If Err.Description <> "" Then MsgBox Err.Description
'MsgBox Err.Description


End Function
```